# Problem regarding calculation in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

The problem with this code is I'm getting the popularity of an author as 0% (I mean zero percent if the number of borrowed books is 14 and the total number of books borrowed of the selected author is 3 - it should be 21.42%). Why is this happening?

All result are correct except the last one:

Author  is 0 % popular (for above given data)

```
<%
String requestedoprations = request.getParameter("popularity");
if("check".equalsIgnoreCase(requestedoprations)){
    int num=LimsHandler.getInstance().popularitycheck(
        request.getParameter("selectedauthor"));
    if(num!=0){
        Limsdetails[] list = LimsHandler.getInstance().libsdetails();
        String totbks=list[0].getTot_books();
        String totbrwdbk=list[0].getTot_borrowed_bks();
        int totbksint=Integer.parseInt(totbks);
        int totbrwdbksint=Integer.parseInt(totbrwdbk);
        float per=(num/totbrwdbksint)*100;          
%>
<font color="brown">
    <b>Total No of Books Available in Library is : <%=totbksint %><br></br>
    Out of which <%=totbrwdbksint %> are borrowed.<br></br>
    <b>No of readers reading Author 
        <%=request.getParameter("selectedauthor") %>'s book. : 
        <%=num %></b><br></br>
    <b> Author <%=request.getParameter("selectedauthor") %> is <%=per %> % 
        popular!</b><br></br>
</font>

<%}else{ %>
    <h4 align="center">
        <font color="red">
            <img border="0" src="images/close.PNG" ><br></br>
            Oops! some error occurred!
        </font>
    </h4>
<%
}
out.flush();
%>

<%} %>
```

Comment: Scriptlets are discouraged since 2001. Write Java code in real Java classes. Use taglibs/EL in JSP to control page flow and access data. The HTML <font> tag is deprecated since 1998. Use CSS. And please throw those ancient books/tutorials away and go get decent ones. This all is like roseindia.net style, please ensure that you don't use that site as "reference" as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really a JSP problem - it's how Java deals with integer arithmetic. The relevant lines are:

```
int num = LimsHandler.getInstance().popularitycheck(...);
int totbrwdbksint = Integer.parseInt(totbrwdbk);
float per = (num / totbrwdbksint) * 100;
```

You're performing an "int / int" division and then multiplying by 100. That will perform the division *using integer arithmetic* - so the result will be 0. Multiplying 0 by 100 still gives 0.

The easiest way to fix it is to make one of the values a `float` or `double`. For example:

```
int num = LimsHandler.getInstance().popularitycheck(...);    
float totbrwdbksint = Integer.parseInt(totbrwdbk);
float per = (num / totbrwdbksint) * 100;
```

Alternatively, you could cast within the expression:

```
int num = LimsHandler.getInstance().popularitycheck(...);
int totbrwdbksint = Integer.parseInt(totbrwdbk);
float per = (num / (float) totbrwdbksint) * 100;
```

At this point the division will be performed using floating point arithmetic, and you'll get the answer you expect.

Comment: I personally would also prefer (100*num) / totbrwdbksint. That can up the accuracy a bit if num is significantly smaller than totbrwdbksint.

Comment: great it worked.thanx a lot.can u tell me one more thing.
the result is something like 26.323232 % .i want it to round upto 2 decimaol places .how to do this?

Comment: @extraneon: On the other hand it leads to potential overflow if `num` is very large :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a solution to your original question, but I would recommend learning two new things:

1. JSTL
2. CSS

You should have neither scriptlets nor styling embedded in your JSPs this way.  You'll thank yourself for making the effort some day, because maintaining and restyling your pages will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The way your calcualtion

```
float per=(num/totbrwdbksint)*100
```

is performed is rounding the result of `(num/totbrwdbksint)` to zero.

Try

```
float per=((float)num/(float)totbrwdbksint)*100
```

to get a better result.